# How can I remove multiple inheritance in this example?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

### Background

I have two abstract base classes, `ISolid` and `IBox` which define interfaces for a Solid and a Box, respectively:

```
using std::unique_ptr<IFace> pIFaces;
using std::unique_ptr<IEdge> pIEdge;

class ISolid
{
    public:
        virtual const pIFaces& getFaceVector() const = 0;
        virtual const pIEdges& getEdgeVector() const = 0;
};

class IBox : public ISolid
{
    public:
        virtual inline ~IBox() = default;
        virtual const IFace& front() const = 0;
        virtual const IFace& back() const = 0;
        virtual const IFace& left() const = 0;
        virtual const IFace& right() const = 0;
        virtual const IFace& top() const = 0;
        virtual const IFace& bottom() const = 0;
};
```

Subsequently, I have defined a real implementation of ISolid, `Solid` as follows:

```
class Solid : public ISolid
    {
        public:
            Solid(const TopoDS_Solid& aSolid);
            const pIEdges& getEdgeVector() const override;
            const pIFaces& getFaceVector() const override;
            const TopoDS_Solid& getSolid() const;

        protected:
            TopoDS_Solid mySolid;
            pIEdges myEdges;
            pIFaces myFaces;
    };
```

Finally, I am attempting to define a real implementation of IBox as follows:

```
class Box : public Solid , public IBox
{
    public:
        Box(BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox mkBox);
        ~Box(){};

        const pIFaces& getFaceVector() const override;
        const pIEdges& getEdgeVector() const override;

        const IFace& front() const override;
        const IFace& back() const override;
        const IFace& left() const override;
        const IFace& right() const override;
        const IFace& top() const override;
        const IFace& bottom() const override;
    private:
        BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox myMakeBox;
        std::map<std::string, int> myIndices;
};
```

### Question

How can I change my design in order to avoid the multiple inheritance in `Box`? I would like to keep the `ISolid` and `IBox` interfaces, as this allows me pass around pointers or references to either an `ISolid` or `IBox` without caring about its actual implementation. Also, I have need to manipulate both solid objects and box objects. In other words, `OccSolid` cannot remain virtual.

Is my best bet to remove the inheritance of `Solid` from `Box`, and add a member variable of type `Solid`? I would then have to add code that implements the missing methods from `ISolid` (inherited in `IBox`), and would subsequently have to do this for other `ISolid` inheritors (i.e. `ICylinder`, etc...) I would like to avoid this boilerplate if possible.

### Options Considered

I have considered dropping the inheritance from `ISolid` altogether on `Box`, however I want/need a pointer/reference to an `ISolid` to be able to refer to either a `Solid` or a `Box`. This is because a `Box` **is a** `Solid`. I suppose I *could* duplicate the `ISolid` interface in `IBox` (and `ICylinder` etc...) but this would lead to parallel code bases in the I family of interfaces, and I'd like to avoid that.

Finally, I have also considered using virtual inheritance in `IBox` and `Solid`, in order to solve the death diamond issue. The only problem I have with this approach is that something along the lines of the following code snippet doesn't appear to work:

```
using std::unique_ptr<ISolid> pISolid;
pISolid MakeFusion(const pISolid& shape1, const pISolid& shape2)
{
    const Solid& solid1 = static_cast<const Solid&>(*shape1);
    const Solid& solid2 = static_cast<const Solid&>(*shape2);
    return FusionOf(solid1.getSolid(), solid2.getSolid());
}
```

You can see in this example that `shape1` could be a regular `Solid` while `shape2` could be a `Box` (a more specific type of solid). The compilation error I get with code like this is:

```
src/OccSolidMaker.cpp: In member function ‘virtual BKAL::pISolid Occ::SolidMaker::makeFusion(const pISolid&, const pISolid&) const’:
src/OccSolidMaker.cpp:26:69: error: cannot convert from pointer to base class ‘BKAL::ISolid’ to pointer to derived class ‘Occ::Solid’ because the base is virtual
     const Occ::Solid& occBase = static_cast<const Occ::Solid&>(*base);
                                                                     ^
OccSolidMaker.cpp:27:69: error: cannot convert from pointer to base class ‘BKAL::ISolid’ to pointer to derived class ‘Occ::Solid’ because the base is virtual
     const Occ::Solid& occTool = static_cast<const Occ::Solid&>(*tool);
```

---

Please note, this question is not specifically regarding this compilation error and as such I have not provided a minimal working example to reproduce it.

Comment: You've mentioned `OccSolid` and `OccBox` but you only have used `Solid` and `Box` in your example code, is that correct?

Comment: it is not. I ha e fixed these typos.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to make `class IBox` not inherit from ISolid?  i.e. just make the IBox and ISolid interfaces completely separate/independent from each other.

Comment: Is using virtual inheritance not an option?

Comment: Use virtual inheritance (it should be your default for all "interface" classes).

Comment: I have updated my question to address both suggestions in these comments.

Comment: `const Solid& solid1 = static_cast<const Solid&>(*shape1);` This completely throws the whole purpose of interfaces over board. Why do you do this?

Comment: I don't see the point of your interface here. you don't have behavior, only getter.

Comment: Perhaps I should post a more complete solution? The purpose of the interface is to specify that an `IFace` should provide this getter, but it does not specify *how* the return value of that getter is created/stored. The reason for this is that different implementations of `IFace` may do this differently.

Comment: 1. You have to use `dynamic_cast` when casting from a virtual base. 2. If you know that every `ISolid` is a `Solid`, you simply don't need `ISolid` at all. Just use `Solid` everywhere. Or, alternatively, move `getSolid` up to `ISolid`. Yet another alternative is to make a `MakeFusion` a virtual member of `ISolid` and use multiple dispatch a.k.a. Visitor (this works even not every ISolid is Solid) OTOH if you *don't* know that, you cannot cast or call `getSolid`.